# Give column number of first column with symbol

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So say I have a sheet like the following:

```
Row    1    2    3    4    5    6
1      x                  
2           x             
3      x         x       
4                     x
5           x              x
6                               x
```

And I have another sheet which I want to encapsulate the data with:

```
1st appeared
1
2
1
4
2
6
```

I'm basically trying to construct the second sheet. Is there a way for each row to start at column two and go up to the ith column and display where the first 'x' appears. (Note that we can assume that every row will have at least 1 'x' when the row and column meet forming a diagonal down the entire first sheet) [Note that my first spreadsheet is roughly 5,000 x 5,000 hence why I'd like a nice formula for this instead of doing things by hand =)]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) return the relative position in either a row or column. Use this formula in your second worksheet.

```
=iferror(match("x", sheet1!1:1, 0) - 1, 0)
```

Fill down to retrieve the correct column index or zero if not found. A 1 is subtracted since hte want the position relative to column B. The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) return a default 0 is no match is found. Substitute `""` in place of the zero if you want nothing displayed.